# Footer summary item multiplies by something

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress in order to show the sum of values in a specific value.

My result is working but the items multiply for a reason which I don't know:

[image]

What could the reason be that this happens?

This is the function where i initialize the details `gridview`:

```
private void GridView_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomMasterRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Initialize the details grid 
    GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
    GridView gridView1 = gridView.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex) as GridView;
    gridView1.BeginUpdate();
    gridView1.Columns["ActivityID"].Visible = false;
    gridView1.Columns["ActivityID"].OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;
    gridView1.Columns["IncidentID"].Visible = false;
    gridView1.Columns["Description"].OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;
    gridView1.Columns["Description"].Width = 100;
    gridView1.Columns["TimeSpent"].Width = 0;
    gridView1.Columns["IsBillable"].Width = 50;
    gridView1.EndUpdate();

    //Initialize footer and show the sum of TimeSpent
    gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;    gridView1.Columns["TimeSpent"].Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum, "TimeSpent", "Sum={0}");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-adding the summary each time the event gets called (Whenever you expand a master row to show the details).

To solve that, check if you've already added the summary:

```
if(gridView1.Columns["TimeSpent"].Summary.Count == 0)
   gridView1.Columns["TimeSpent"].Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum, 
                                              "TimeSpent", "Sum={0}");
```

Comment: Thanks but where am I re-adding it then? I just coded it once?

Comment: @KahnKah That event `MasterRowExpanded` gets called multiple times. Each time you expand a Master row.

Comment: thank you very much. Would you recommend me to initialize my details elsewhere then maybe?

Comment: @KahnKah I don't think you have access to the details grid elsewhere. But it has been a while since I've worked with DevExpress, so my statement might not be correct.